# Setvalue to add usercontrol in a grid not work

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to programmatically insert a user control in a row.
This is my userControl:

```
public sealed partial class ItemWeek : UserControl
{
    public string nome {get;set;}
    private string luogo { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataInizio { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataFine { get; set; }

    public ItemWeek()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    public ItemWeek(string nome, string luogo, DateTime dataInizio, DateTime dataFine)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.luogo = luogo;
        this.dataInizio = dataInizio;
        this.dataFine = dataFine;
    }

}


<Grid>
    <Grid Height="60" Width="80">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{x:Bind nome}" FontSize="23" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{x:Bind luogo}" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want to do is simply place the control in a row of the grid, the method setvalue does not work for the user control.

```
  grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

        ItemWeek ite = new ItemWeek("string", "string", dat, dat1);
        ite.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        ite.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        grid1.Children.Add(ite);
```

but if I try to insert a textblock works:

```
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Text = "teeeext";

        txt.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        txt.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        grid1.Children.Add(txt);
```

why and how can I do? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `InitializeComponent()` in the second constructor.

Either call it directly like this:

```
public ItemWeek(string nome, string luogo, DateTime dataInizio, DateTime dataFine)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.nome = nome;
    this.luogo = luogo;
    this.dataInizio = dataInizio;
    this.dataFine = dataFine;
}
```

Or call the parameterless constructor like this:

```
public ItemWeek(string nome, string luogo, DateTime dataInizio, DateTime dataFine)
   : this()
{
    this.nome = nome;
    this.luogo = luogo;
    this.dataInizio = dataInizio;
    this.dataFine = dataFine;
}
```

There is probably no need to have the second constructor at all, because you could also use an object initializer like this:

```
var ite = new ItemWeek
{
    nome = "string",
    luogo = "string",
    dataInizio = dat,
    dataFine = dat1
};
```

---

You should also use the static methods `Grid.SetColumn()` and `Grid.SetRow()` instead of `SetValue()`:

```
Grid.SetRow(ite, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(ite, 0);
```

Calling these methods is not strictly necessary, as long as you do not set any other value than the default value `0`.

Comment: Note that the `luogo` property should also be public, not private. Otherwise the binding won't work.